# Relation between some JIRA database tables

Tags: database, jira

I want to understand JIRA database, but I couldn't understand the relation between the tables `nodeAssocation`, `project` and `workflowscheme` in terms of entity-relationship.

Is `nodeassociation` an association between the two tables `project` and `workflowscheme`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to understand the relationship is to have a look at values in association_type
For instance doing following query

```
SELECT association_type FROM `nodeassociation` group by association_type;
```

You get

- IssueComponent
- IssueFixVersion
- IssueVersion
- ProjectCategory
- ProjectScheme

For instance for

```
SELECT * FROM `nodeassociation` where association_type = 'IssueFixVersion';
```

you get the values

```
10010, Issue, 10003, Version, IssueFixVersion
```

Which relates issue with id 10010 with version with id 10003

That way you get access to the fixVersions associated to a particular issue.
Similarly you get an association between issues an components and so on..

Hope this helps,

Francis